# Help with solution to 2 variable quadratic equation.

Tags: quadratics

Could someone help with an explanation on how to treat the equation below, please?
A solution I have read uses the discriminant to find the range i.e. $9-20y^2-16y>or = 0$.
To me this means treating the variable Y as a constant , is that "acceptable" ? does anyone have a reference for these equations ?

$yx^2+5y-3x+4=0$

rewrite as
$yx^2-3x+(5y+4)=0$

thanks
ralph

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: To expand on herb's point, what are you trying to achieve? Solve x in terms of y, y in terms of x, finding values of y for which x is real? Etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I take from $$yx^2-3x+(5y+4)\ge 0~~~(1)$$
A quadratic $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ is positive definite for all real values of $x$ if $B^2\le 4AC$ and $A>0$
So (1) will hold for all real values of $x$ if $y>0$ and
$B^2 \le 4AC$. So we get
$$9 \le 4y(5y+4) \implies 20y^2+6y-9 \ge 0  $$ $$ \implies \left(x-\frac{4+\sqrt{61}}{10}\right) \left(x-\frac{4-\sqrt{61}}{10}\right) \ge 0 $$ So
$$\implies  y \ge \frac{4+\sqrt{61}}{10} ~or~ y \le \frac{4-\sqrt{61}}{10}$$
But due to the condition $y>0$, we finally get
$$ y \ge \frac{4+\sqrt{61}}{10}.$$

Comment: Hello , my confusion( what I'm asking) , in the quadratic formula above

Comment: Yes you can treat it as a quadratic of $x$  and treat  $y$ as constant.